# AWS Kinesis firehose - query current stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Is there a way to query AWS Kinesis Firehose for current stats such as

- Number of records in current buffer?
- how much of the buffer is consumed?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few metrics that you can get from CloudWatch for Kinesis Firehose: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/monitoring.html

Note that these metrics are aggregated on a minute base. You can compare the numbers for PutRecord(batch), Incoming.Records and DeliveryToS3.Records